# What is the solution to the following Cauchy problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

[image]

What I have tried to do was to separate variables and integrate both sides but what I got was y+ln|y-3|=ln|t-3| + c
which is undefined for y=3 and t=3. but I don't understand how to get the range for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(t) = \dfrac{1}{t-3}$ has a vertical asymptote at $t=3$ which divides the graph of $f(t)$ into two separate parts. Since the initial condition is at time $t=0$, the solution $y(t)=3$ is defined on the interval $(-\infty,3)$.

Comment: can you please point to some of the resources to understand this?

Comment: @M.HamzaAli I don't really know of any specific resources, but you can try dynamical system textbook?